# Javascript - timeupdate event listener for Embed object

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, embed, vlc, addeventlistener

To Hooking up the Seek Bar, I am using following code. I am able to seek the vide but the seekbar is not moving as the video move forward

**HTML**

```
    <embed pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
    type="application/x-vlc-plugin"
    width="640"
    height="480"
    toolbar="true"
    loop="false"
    text="Waiting for video"
    windowless="true"
    bgcolor="#000000"
    branding="true"
    allowfullscreen="true"
    src="./videos/mikethefrog.mp4"
    id="video"
    name="vlc" />
   <input type="range" id="seek-bar" value="0" onChange='seekBar();'>
```

**JS**

```
    window.onload = function() {

        var vlc = getVLC("vlc");

        // Update the seek bar as the video plays
        var video = document.getElementById("video");
        var seekBar = document.getElementById("seek-bar");
        var mediaLen = vlc.input.length;

        video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {

        // Calculate the slider value
        var value = (100 / mediaLen) * vlc.input.time;

        // Update the slider value
        seekBar.value = value;
        });

     function seekBar(){

    var vlc = getVLC("vlc");
    var seekBar = document.getElementById("seek-bar");
    var mediaLen = vlc.input.length;

    // Event listener for the seek bar
    seekBar.addEventListener("change", function() {

        // Calculate the new time
        var time = mediaLen * (seekBar.value / 100);

        // Update the video time
        vlc.input.time = time;
                //vlc.playlist.play();

                console.log(vlc.input.time);
    });


    // Pause the video when the seek handle is being dragged
    seekBar.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
            console.log('pause');
                vlc.playlist.pause();
    });

    // Play the video when the seek handle is dropped
    seekBar.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
            console.log('play');
        vlc.playlist.play();
    });
}

}
```

**Exception**

`Error: Error calling method on NPObject!
video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {`

Comment: does 'vlc.input.time' produce anything? if so you could just use an interval

Comment: 'vlc.input.time` gives me the absolute position in time given in millisecond. How do I use interval with it ?

Comment: var tracker= setInterval(track_audio, 100);
function track_audio() {//Your tracking code}

Comment: Could you post an answer pertaining the code I posted above ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this as a global:

```
var tracker;
```

Remove this section of code:

```
video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {

        // Calculate the slider value
        var value = (100 / mediaLen) * vlc.input.time;

        // Update the slider value
        seekBar.value = value;
});
```

Replace in this area:

```
tracker= setInterval(track_audio, 100);
```

Now to track the audio:

```
function track_audio() {
    var vlc = getVLC("vlc");
    var seekBar = document.getElementById("seek-bar");
    var mediaLen = vlc.input.length;

    // Calculate the slider value
    var value = (100 / mediaLen) * vlc.input.time;

    // Update the slider value
    seekBar.value = value;
}
```